# How do I use the C.L.I. to convert packages in the output from apt-cache depends into a space‐separated list for use with apt-get download?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies, apt-cache

How do I use the command line interface (not a GUI) to convert the list of dependency packages in the output from `apt-cache depends` into a space‐separated list for use with `apt-get download`? Preferably, I’d like the two actions to be executable via a single command.

(By “list of dependency packages”, I’m referring to all packages prefixed by the string “`Depends:`”.)

The use case is to download all dependent packages of a package onto a machine with Internet access for use on a machine without Internet access as well as to teach myself how to reformat text via the command line.

One example with a long list of dependencies involves the command `apt-cache depends gimp`, the output of which is shown below. (This example includes a few dependencies listed multiple times, but `apt-get download` apparently ignores duplicate entries, so there’s no need to filter them out.)

```
gimp
  Depends: libgimp2.0
  Depends: libgimp2.0
  Depends: gimp-data
  Depends: gimp-data
  Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
  Depends: xdg-utils
  Depends: libaa1
  Depends: libbabl-0.1-0
  Depends: libbz2-1.0
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libcairo2
  Depends: libfontconfig1
  Depends: libfreetype6
  Depends: libgcc1
  Depends: libgegl-0.4-0
  Depends: libgexiv2-2
  Depends: libglib2.0-0
  Depends: libgs9
  Depends: libgtk2.0-0
  Depends: libgudev-1.0-0
  Depends: libharfbuzz0b
  Depends: libheif1
  Depends: libilmbase23
  Depends: libjpeg8
  Depends: liblcms2-2
  Depends: liblzma5
  Depends: libmng2
  Depends: libmypaint-1.3-0
  Depends: libopenexr23
  Depends: libopenjp2-7
  Depends: libpango-1.0-0
  Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0
  Depends: libpangoft2-1.0-0
  Depends: libpng16-16
  Depends: libpoppler-glib8
  Depends: librsvg2-2
  Depends: libstdc++6
  Depends: libtiff5
  Depends: libwebp6
  Depends: libwebpdemux2
  Depends: libwebpmux3
  Depends: libwmf0.2-7
  Depends: libx11-6
  Depends: libxcursor1
  Depends: libxext6
  Depends: libxfixes3
  Depends: libxmu6
  Depends: libxpm4
  Depends: zlib1g
  Breaks: gimp-plugin-registry
  Recommends: ghostscript
    ghostscript:i386
 |Suggests: gimp-help-en
  Suggests: <gimp-help>
    gimp-help-ca
    gimp-help-de
    gimp-help-el
    gimp-help-en
    gimp-help-es
    gimp-help-fr
    gimp-help-it
    gimp-help-ja
    gimp-help-ko
    gimp-help-nl
    gimp-help-nn
    gimp-help-pt
    gimp-help-ru
    gimp-help-sl
    gimp-help-sv
  Suggests: gimp-data-extras
  Suggests: gimp-python
  Suggests: gvfs-backends
    gvfs-backends:i386
  Suggests: libasound2
    liboss4-salsa-asound2
  Replaces: gimp-plugin-registry
```

Comment: Why would you need that? `apt install gimp` will automatically take care of any dependencies (even recursively) of that package and download and install them along with `gimp`.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. `apt install gimp` automatically installs all dependencies. The only time you may see "depends" in errors is when a dependency is unmet. That is, there is a version conflict.

Comment: `apt install gimp` can’t fulfill dependencies while performing an offline installation hence the mention of `apt-get download`.

Comment: Ok, that's a valid reason. But maybe you want to have a look at this question: [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/974/504066)

Comment: Please edit your question and indicate the question is about offline install.

Comment: There’s no duplicate involved here. This question is more about being able to perform a series of actions solely using the command line than learning how to install packages on a machine in an offline state, which I already know how to do. I’ve revised and answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I arrived at is `apt-get download $(apt-cache depends gimp | while read line; do grep --only-matching --perl-regexp "(?<= Depends: ).+"; done | tr "\n" " ")` using the package `gimp` as an example.

Explanation:

- Run `apt-cache depends` as a subshell argument to `apt-get download`.
- On the initial subshell output, use a `while` loop that that splits the output into lines assigned to the variable `line`—which can be named anything and is otherwise not required—using the `read` command.
- For each line of output, use the `grep` command with a Perl regular expression. enabled with the flag `--perl-regexp`, that utilizes a positive lookbehind involving the string “`Depends:`”, and only display the matched text using the flag `--only-matching`.
- Finally, translate all newline characters into space characters using the `tr` command.